# How does excerpt work in bolt and what are the accepted parameters?

Tags: php, twig, bolt-cms

I was just going through the default twig theme files in bolt CMS and came across the following lines of code:

```
 <p>{{ record.excerpt(300, false, search|default('')) }}</p>
```

Now i checked the bolt docs to see how the excerpt functions works and i came across the following lines of code:

> Create a short excerpt from var, without HTML formatting, restricted
>   by length characters. var can be a 'record' object, a single value
>   from a 'record' or a regular string.*

But in the above peice of code there is a third parameter being passed which i dont quite understand I.E. `search|default('')` , Also what is `false` for ?

I was just glancing though the cheetsheet in the bolt docs **[HERE](https://docs.bolt.cm/3.1/cheatsheet#bolt-functions-in-twig)** , but the definition listed there does't match the usage , can somebody clarify how this function works ??

Comment: I'm not sure that this is the call of a twig function, seems instead of a method call on the record object. Could the record object have a method named excerpt? a twig filter call to [excerpt](https://docs.bolt.cm/3.1/templating/templatetags#excerpt) example is more similar to `{{ text|excerpt(10) }}`

Comment: yes its a twig method in bolt :D i have the link in my question and yes the example i gave does't match what the documentation says , thats whats confuing me even more :D

Comment: in the doc, an example of function is similar to `{{excerpt(record, 300)
 }}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, this is another funky part of Twig. It a "filter" that just tells Twig, that if a variable doesn't exist, give it a default value, e.g.

```
{{ var|default('var is not defined') }}
```

In the example you posted, that would just set the value to an empty string if it doesn't exist.

More information on that filter http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/default.html

Comment: thanks for being patient and answering my questions , but what i wanted to know is each of the parameters for the excerpt fucntion , so the  first parameter is `300` , thats the no. of characters i want in the excerpt , now why the 2nd parameter `false` ? and lastly why the 3nd parameter `search` ?? where is this coming from ? :) if you could break it down a little this way it would be really helpful .

Comment: Derpy derp … I needed more coffee apparently :-)

The 300 is the number of characters in the excerpt, the false should be "use a title", but just double checking the code we might have no implemented that yet, and the "search" is the word to centre the except text around … class that Twig calls is here https://github.com/bolt/bolt/blob/release/3.1/src/Helpers/Excerpt.php#L35

Comment: so the secound parameter is the default text , if i am understanding this right ? :)